# Redeclaration hides member in base class

Tags: delphi

I am trying to clean up compiler warnings in an application I inherited. One of our classes inherits from TControl. The warning I am getting is "Redeclaration of Changed hides a member in the Base class"

"Changed" is a protected procedure in TControl. The class I am looking at has overridden it with a boolean property

`property Changed : Boolean read FChanged write FChanged stored true;`

There are a few options I have ruled out already:

1. Rename from "Changed" to something else. This is not a practical option, as this property is used everywhere in the application.
2. Hide the warning using compiler directives. I can do this but I would prefer to find out what the warning means and how to correct it.

So my question is:

1) Is this warning actually a problem? What are the implications of "hiding the base member"?

2) How can I remove the compiler warning without renaming the property or hiding the warning?

I am using Delphi 2010

[Edit: There have been a few suggesions of using the refactoring tool to rename the offending property. I have ruled this out as the refactoring tool doesn't work at all on this codebase]

Comment: The warning is valid. It means that you won't be able to call `TControl.Changed` from within your new control. Your control needs to call that to notify itself and its parent that its properties have changed. They're watching for the `cm_Changed` message that that method sends. Consider calling your property `Dirty` instead. (Besides, it sounds like a strange property to want to store in the DFM; upon loading a new instance of the form, is it really correct to say that the control has changed?)

Comment: Good point! No idea why it is stored.

Answer (score 5):

If your own 'Changed' was a procedure as well, you could use the override directive to tell the compiler that you add functionality to the base Changed method in TControl. If your declaration differs or you want for some other reason to break the chain of inheritance, you could specify the reintroduce directive to tell the compiler that you conciously break the chain.

Unfortunately this is not possible with properties, so there is no real solution for your problem, other than

1. Rename 'Changed' to something else
2. Hide the warning using directives
3. Don't inherit from TControl

I would opt for the first option. Since you are using Delphi 2010, you can use the Refactoring tools in Delphi to rename the property thoughout your application, although I would thoroughly check the modifications before making them final, because maybe they will affect the Changed method in the base class as well...

Comment: Don't worry about the possibility of the rename refactoring tool accidentally renaming the method. First, that shouldn't happen because they refer to distinct things; that's what distinguishes the refactoring tool from a simple find-and-replace. And second, if the wrong thing *does* happen, the compiler will tell you exactly where each problem is because the code won't compile anymore — you can't use the `Changed` property in a context where the `Changed` method would be expected.

Comment: You *couldn't* add `override` to the declaration, even if `Changed` were a method. The method in the base class is not virtual.

Comment: The refactoring tool doesn't work on my project. I just tried as you suggested and it doesn't rename usages in other projects in the Project Group.

Comment: Maybe you could use the refactoring tool on each of your projects. That still wouldn't be much less work than manually fixing all of your code.